# Can I group multiple objects in UI router resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to load 3 services up front in Resolve , rather than creating seperate service calls for each, will it be possible to return a object of functions

My router

```
.state('home.movies', {
                parent: 'home',
                url: '/home/movies/edit/:id',
                data: {
                    roles: []
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/admin/activity-edit.html',
                        controller: 'ActivityEditController'
                    }     
                },
                resolve: 
                    titles:function (MovieService){
                       return {
                           actors: function (MovieService) {                            
                              return MovieService.getActors('','','N');
                            },
                           actresses:function (MovieService) {                            
                             return ResourceService.getActresses();
                           },
                          timemap:function(MovieService){
                             return MovieService.getTimemap();                      
                           }
                       }
                    }

            });
    })
```

my Controller

```
.controller('MovieEditController', function ($scope,titles,MovieService) {
```

refere is as

```
 $scope.moviesActors=titles.actors;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with `$q`:

```
resolve: {
   titles: function (MovieService, $q){
       return $q.all({
           actors: MovieService.getActors('','','N'),
           actresses: ResourceService.getActresses(),
           timemap: MovieService.getTimemap()
       });
   }
}
```

Resolved `titles` will look like: `{ actors: [], actresses: [], timemap: {} }`

Comment: thanks , but I cant use `$q`, beaucse it is not allowed.

by following your way came up with this, is it correct to do like this

`resolve: {
   titles: function (MovieService){
       return (
           actors: MovieService.getActors('','','N'),
           actresses: ResourceService.getActresses(),
           timemap: MovieService.getTimemap()
       );
   }
}`

all call it


`titles.actors.then(function (obj){
                $scope.actors=obj;}
                , function(error,status) {
                        alert(error);
                    });`